# Text will not center?

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with text not being aligned in the center of a DIV.

I have tried:

```
text-align:center;
```

and

```
width:225px; /*width of div*/ 
margin:0px auto;
```

and it will not center.

Here is the HTML and CSS for the DIV.

**HTML**

```
<div id="past">
<h3><a href="/artistphotos/">View Past Messages</a></h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#past{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:363px;
    width:225px;
    height:50px;
    background-image:url('../images/members/roundedbox.png');
    z-index:10;
}
```

I have applied the text-align and margin using inline styles while I was building the page. I have applied it to the div, h3, and a elements and it won't work in any of them.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

**Here is the HTML Code: (excluding the header and footer elements)**

```
<div class="center over_all_under">
</div>
<!--[if !IE]>start intro<![endif]-->
<div class="center">
</div>
<!--[if !IE]>end intro<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>strat main<![endif]-->
<div class="wrap_fullwidth" id="main">
<div class="center">
<br />
<div id="homepage">
    <div id="homepage-main">
        <div id="homepage-main-item" class="full_shadow>{module_adrotator,5622}
        <div id="past">
          <h3><a href="/artistphotos/">View Past Messages</a></h3>
        </div>
```

**This is followed by a lot of code. I could paste it here but because it is hard to read I only included the code above the div.**

Comment: did you try text-align:center inside your #past css rules?

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/LzETm/

Comment: Yes I did and does not work. Firebug shows the rule there and it is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align:center;` works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/bhtZe/

```
#past {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:363px;
    width:225px;
    height:50px;
    background-image:url('../images/members/roundedbox.png');
    z-index:10;
    text-align:center;    
}
```

**Update:** After looking at the page, remove `position: absolute` from `#past h3` as that is preventing the href from center aligning (it gets absolutely positioned).

Also, your div width is small, if you intent to center it on parent background, set `#past width` to `100%`.

Comment: Can you post your page HTML then?

Comment: Added some HTML code, makes it hard to post all as the page is long, also posted link to page.

Comment: It is centered in the div. Your div's width is small, so it seems this is not centered.

Comment: Also, your h3 is positioned absolute which is preventin gthe href from centering. See my updated answer.

Comment: I messed with it a bit and I made the h3 relative positing and the text finally moved but it does not look exactly center (a little to the right is the text) thoughts?

Comment: Remove `left: 10px` from `h3`.

Comment: Was completely missing that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have `position:absolute`  With absolutely positioned elements, they are taken out of the flow, and the `margin` doesn't mean anything.

You can try centering the image by putting it inside a different absolutely positioned `DIV`, which has a width of `100%`.  Then leave `#past` with a `relative` position, and use the margin trick.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/c5xaW/

Comment: It is text not an image I need center aligned.

Comment: I was centering the outer div.  If it's just the text, the same issue applies.  You have to assign a `width`, and then use `test-align: center` - but you need *both* because the div has no width when it is absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of you `#past` css rules, add this:

```
text-align: center;
```

It should work. I tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LzETm/). Try adding and removing the rule and see what happens.